# ufw iptables-nat module not found after update to linux-images-5.8.0-12-generic Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, iptables, ufw

Anyones got a problem with iptables with the new kernel update ?

I try to do a modprobe iptables-nat but it's like the modules is not part of the new kernel.

When I choose kernel 5.4.0-42 in grub it work fine.

I tried to reinstall linux-image-5.8.0-12-generic just in case but it does not work.

Got a message a startup that the "Uncomplicated Firewall" could not start.

Comment: kernel 5.8.0-12 is not in the standard 20.04 repositories.  Are you tracking a different custom branch or the Mainline kernels (which are not officially supported)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built the kernel by myself. They excluded iptables modules from their builds due to the migration on nft firewall subsytem. Mine libvirt setup doesn't support nftables yet, so i decided to add modules and rebuild 5.8 kernel, now it's ok.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, I just uninstalled iptables completly, redo the upgrade and then reinstall nftables instead.

Comment: I install firewalld after the update to help.